# PostGIS: Get portion of length in polygon. Aggregate value by this portion

Tags: postgis, geometry, spatial-join, grids-sum

I have a table that has two points (made into a line) and a value per row. I have another table that is a grid that has a geometry and id per row. I'd like to aggregate the data in such a way that each grid geometry has the sum of the portion of values that are in each grid geometry.

```
this_bin_value = SUM[(Line length in this bin) / (Length of Line) * (Some Value) ]
```

Sort of like this:

```
SELECT
    grid.gid,
    grid.geom,
    sum(ST_Length(ST_Intersection(grid.geom,data.line)/ST_Length(data.line) * data.my_value
FROM
    geo.grid_rough LEFT JOIN data
ON ST_Intersects(grid.geom, data.line) 
GROUP BY grid.gid;
```

Problem is I keep getting divide by zero when Point 1 == Point 2. Is there a better way to do this? I got this working a couple months back but, like an idiot, I didn't save the code and can't recreate it.

MORE INFO- In the hope that someone can figure this out from the first table:

The data table has Vehicle_ID, time and position in it. I'm using a window function to create time, lead(time), position and lead(position) on Vehicle_ID. The "value" I want to spread over the grid is (lead(Time) - Time) so that I can get "amount of time vehicles spent in grid(x,y)".

Comment: okay, now that I read it more carefully, I deleted my former comments ,) try adding `WHERE ST_Length(data.line) > 0`...

Comment: Of course, so obvious!